# Opening a specified view using custom url

Tags: ios, custom-url

I have one enterprise application and am working on a second to couple with the first. The second is a reader application to hold numerous pdf documents for the user to review. They can access the reader app from the first using custom url. I want the reader application to open based on the view the use is on in the first application. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

look,
On the index.html
e.g. for an external link

```
<a href="https://m.facebook.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="imag/facebook.png" width="50" height="50" alt="fb"></a>
```

on the Cordova.plist

> UIWebViewBounce **YES**
>
> OpenAllWhitelisURLsInWebWiew **NO**
>
> ExternalHosts
>   ***.facebook.com**

OK!! :)